# Android JNI APK Packing

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have implemented a JNI android application. This application requires a few additional 'Shared Libs' to be packed as part of the APK. Using Ecplise, I have added these libs to the project's '/libs/armeabi' folder.

However, when launching the application (through the integrated debugger), my added 'Shared Libs' are removed from the 'armeabi' folder.

- How can I prevent these additional libs from being removed?
- How can I make sure the additional required SOs are packed in the APK?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to copy this libraries to `libs` folder yourself. This job should be done by the `ndk-build`.

These two steps should be enough:

1. Create `mylibs` (you can use any other name instead) folder on the root level of your project. And put your libraries into this folder.
2. For each library add the following lines before the `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` statement replacing `mylib` with you library name:

   ```
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE:=mylib
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=../mylibs/libmylib.so
   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

(You might need slightly different path for `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. It depends on your Eclipse configuration.)

Comment: Having the above done, this is what I get during the build process:ndroid NDK: jni/Android.mk:swscale: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions    
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:swscale: LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".a"

Comment: Fixed. There should be `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` instead of `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY`.

Answer (score 1):

One more note to add in this context is that the path to the external SharedLib MUST BE relative to the jni directory ( or to whatever spcified @ LOCAL_PATH ), that is, "LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../Android/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libavcodec.so" will work where the absolute path will not.